# PHP PDO fetch data from mysql and echo them out

Tags: php, mysql

I know it will be very easy for some, but I'm pretty new to the subject. I am trying to read the following values ​​from my database for a normal HTML page that should take the values ​​from the database instead of having to change it in the HTML.
The whole thing should not happen in a table, but rather it should simply output the value in different areas via ECHO.

Example with my Code what i've done but stuck at how to echo just the value.

```
    $sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT text_beschreibung FROM magical_moments_text");
    $sth->execute();

    $result = $sth->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_NUM);
    var_dump($result);
```

Result is this

```
    array(3) { 
        [0]=> array(1) {
             [0]=> string(2) "33" 
        } 
        [1]=> array(1) {
             [0]=> string(3) "555" 
        } 
        [2]=> array(1) { 
            [0]=> string(3) "444" 
        } 
    }
```

Now comes the part where I don't know what to do next. I don't want to output var_dump but only the values ​​that are in the "". But the whole thing should work like this

```
echo $result[1];
```

for the final example what I mean i'm trying to explain it like this

```
<?php
$sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT text_beschreibung FROM magical_moments_text");
$sth->execute();

$result = $sth->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_NUM);
    
?>
<html>
    <body>
        <p>The following code should give me <?php echo $result[0]; //33 ?></p>     
        <p>The following code should give me <?php echo $result[1]; //555 ?></p>        
        <p>The following code should give me <?php echo $result[2]; //444 ?></p>        
    </body>
</html>
```

If I use this methode it will gives me this

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in
```

Hopefully I explained it good enough. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Replace `$result[0]` by  `$result[0][0]` , `$result[1]` by  `$result[1][0]` and `$result[2]` by `$result[2][0]`  , you may also use loops to make things easy .

Comment: Thanks this was the answer i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

usually I do something like this

```
$qry = "SELECT text_beschreibung FROM magical_moments_text";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($qry); # good practice on using prepared stmt
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

and then loop the $result

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo("<p>The following code should give me ". $row['text_beschreibung'] ."</p>");
}
```

Comment: I'm using PDO and your code looks like mysqli I think? Anyways, this is not the answer I was lookin for. As I asked in my question, i'm trying to echo in <p></p> tags. 

```
33555444 
```

This is the ouput of your code, but I just need 1 value only means, 33 or 555 or 444 of them.

Comment: woops my bad, noob is trying to help :))